# Is lo (咯) valid pinyin?

Tags: pinyin

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E5%92%AF) and [Baidu](https://dict.baidu.com/s?wd=%E5%92%AF) provide a pronunciation of 咯 (as in the sentence-final particle indicating that something is obvious) as lo5. "lo" isn't listed on [Wikipedia's pinyin table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin_table), and I thought only bo/po/mo/fo could drop the *u* from *-uo*. Is this the standard pinyin? Is "lo" pronounced the same as "luo"?

Comment: 有四种读法：gē、kǎ、luò、lo

Comment: I think the final particle "lo" is probably not native Mandarin, and is probably borrowed from 囉 in Cantonese or other southern Chinese languages.

Answer (score 2):

## Definition

According to yabla, 'Io' is a valid pinyin.
Quoting yabla:

> 咯 
>   luò
>
> ---
>
> to cough up
>
> ---
>
> > 咯 
> >     lo
> >
> > ---
> >
> > (final particle similar to 了, indicating that sth is obvious)
> >
> > ---
>
> 咯 
>   gē
>
> ---
>
> (phonetic)

## Usage

Example Usage just for that middle one(from yabla):

**哟呵呵呵我们回来咯回来了回来了**

**yohēhēāwǒmenhuílailohuílailehuílaile**

English:
Ha ha ha ha! We are back. -You are back. You are back.

## Sidenotes

A pinyin table from allsetlearning:

[image: pinyin table]

That proves to me that lo is a valid pinyin.

Comment: Come to think of it, the Wikipedia table is also missing *o*, which is a pretty big omission.

Comment: @MiCl no it isn’t, *o* is the very first row/column entry. ø- (first row) is a None initial, so *øo* is *o*.

Comment: @droooze oh yeah, I edited the Wikipedia article after I posted that comment to add an -o row, so now it has *o* and *lo*

Comment: @MiCl oh you just added that? my bad...